# What's the difference between functions w/ and w/o parentheses?

Tags: python, function, object

now I'm reading Think Python,currently going through Chapter 4, but I have a question.

In 4.1 The turtle module, there is something like:

```
>>> import turtle

>>> bob = turtle.Turtle()
```

And that really got me confused. I thought a function name w/o parentheses(like print, math.sqrt or int) represents the function object, and a function name w/ parentheses stands for the return value of that func. So I thought turtle.Turtle() should mean the value for that func after it's executed.

But then the book told me:
"The turtle module (with a lowercase ’t’) provides a function called Turtle (with an uppercase ’T’) that creates a Turtle object, which we assign to a variable named bob."

OK, and then I've had a try. When bob was assigned turtle.Turtle(), I got:

```
>>> type(bob)

    <class 'turtle.Turtle>
```

but if I did bob=turtle.Turtle,I got:

```
>>> type(bob)

    <class 'type'>

>>> print(bob)

    <class 'turtle.Turtle>
```

Another thing really baffles me...

I read this book as, like my programming 101 book, so I don't know where did they come from.
Could anyone answer the question and tell me a little more about the concept of 'object'?

Comment: Your own description trivially explains its pretty well, "I thought a function name w/o parentheses(like print, math.sqrt or int) represents the function object, and a function name w/ parentheses stands for the return value of that func" You're working with a class instance/class here though

Comment: @RussJ no, that isn't what is happening. `turtle` is a module, and `Turtle` is a class  (or maybe just function, but in this case a class) in that module.

Comment: "And that really got me confused. I thought a function name w/o parentheses(like print, math.sqrt or int) represents the function object, and a function name w/ parentheses stands for the return value of that func." This is essentially correct. To phrase it a little more precisely, w/ parentheses is an *function call expression*, which *evaluates* to the return value of the function. I

Comment: "The concept of 'object" is widely covered in tutorials. You can find many great tutorials on the internet, but Stack Overflow is not one of them. Please take the [tour], and read [ask] and [what's on-topic](/help/on-topic). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Yeah, so, Python is an object-oriented language, *everything* is an object. integers, strings, floats, `None`, functions, etc etc. Basically, for now, you can think of an object as anything you can assign to a variable. So if you can do `x = <whatever>` then "whatever" is an object.

Comment: So, when you create an object, say you do `my_list = list()` (although frequently, people use the *literal notation*, `my_list = []`), you've called the *list class* to create a new list object. So, if you do `type(my_list)` you get `<class 'list'>`, just like `bob = Turtle()` you get `<class 'Turtle'>`. One metaphor is that classes are like "blueprints" for creating objects. Note, in Python, *classes are objects themselves*. `type(list)` will give you... `<class 'type'>` because all classes are instances of the class `type`! These are "metaclasses", but that's a bit of advanced stuff

Comment: Thank you very much guys, especially @juanpa.arrivillaga .    going to find some tutorials for these class thing now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`turtle.Turtle` is a class, not a function (though both are in a class of things referred to as "callables", stuff you can put parentheses after to trigger other code to execute). When you fail to call it, you're just aliasing the class itself; `bob = turtle.Turtle` just gives you another name you could use to construct `turtle.Turtle` objects, so you could (if you liked), do:

```
bob = turtle.Turtle
myturtle = bob()
myturtle2 = bob()
```

as a way to avoid typing out the full name, while getting the same effect as:

```
myturtle = turtle.Turtle()
myturtle2 = turtle.Turtle()
```

The `type(bob)` in this case returns `<class 'type'>` because Python classes are themselves instances of a "metaclass"; when not otherwise specified, they're implicitly instance of `type` (the ultimate root metaclass for all classes).

Basically, your book was a little imprecise (it's a class, not a function), but it's correct on behavior; `bob = turtle.Turtle()` *creates* an instance of `turtle.Turtle`, `bob = turtle.Turtle` just *aliases* `turtle.Turtle` to a new name, `bob`, without actually making an instance of it.

Comment: That's so detailed! Thank you very much, it did help.

Answer (score 0):

> In 4.1 The turtle module, there is something like:
>
> `import turtle`
>
> `bob = turtle.Turtle()`
>
> And that really got me confused. I thought a function name w/o
> parentheses(like print, math.sqrt or int) represents the function
> object, and a function name w/ parentheses stands for the return value
> of that func. So I thought turtle.Turtle() should mean the value for
> that func after it's executed.
>
> But then the book told me: "The turtle module (with a lowercase ’t’)
> provides a function called Turtle (with an uppercase ’T’) that creates
> a Turtle object, which we assign to a variable named bob."

Both statements are correct. In this case the function object is turtle.Turtle

You can return a Turtle object using the syntax turtle.Turtle(). You can think of the Turtle object as the value returned by the function.

> OK, and then I've had a try. When bob was assigned turtle.Turtle(), I got:
>
> `type(bob)`
>
> `>>> <class 'turtle.Turtle>`
>
> but if I did:
>
> `bob=turtle.Turtle`
>
> I got:*
>
> `type(bob)`
>
> `>>> <class 'type'>`

When you write 'bob = turtle.Turtle' you aren't returning a turtle object because you didn't use the parenthesis. You're actually assigning the turtle.Turtle function to a variable called bob. That's basically the same thing as creating an alias for the turtle.Turtle function.

In your example, if you were to then enter type(bob()) you would see that bob() returns a Turtle object.